# Microcontroller PIC16(L)F18426/46 ADC Clock Period (TAD) Vs. Device Operating Frequencies

Tags: adc

I have to configure the ADC peripheral with the following specifications:

Microcontroller: PIC16F18446;
Oscillator frequency: 12MHz;
ADC pin: ANA2;
Supply voltage: 5V;
ADC clock period: TAD=1µs;
Temperature: 25°C;
External circuit resistance: Rs=5kQ;
Measured voltage: 1.1V;
Voltage references: 0-5V;

Some of the registries are already configured and must be taken into account.

Complete the configurations in the following example:

```
// Fosc=12MHz

TRISAbits.TRISA2= 1;

ANSELAbits.ANSA2= 1 ;

ADCONObits.CS = 0;

ADCLK= 0B....... ; //TAD=1μς
```

Here I know that the ADCLK register is configured according to the given TAD value and the Fosc=12MHz oscillator frequency. I normally take the value from the table, but I don't have it in the table and I don't know which clock source will correspond to it.
How to proceed?
https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/pic16f18446

Comment: Study the PIC manual carefully, you will surely find the answer to all your problems.

Comment: Yep. Very helpful, I really didn't know that. Thanks!